# Не работает $(this) JQuery

Tags: jquery, this

JS

```
$('.change-definite-page').click(() => {
    console.log($(this).attr('data-page'))
})
```

HTML

```
<ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
    <li class="page-item change-definite-page" data-page=1>
        <button class="page-link">1</button>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item change-definite-page" data-page=2>
        <button class="page-link">2</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Пробовал $(this) менять на $('.change-definite-page') и все работало, то есть выводилось "1" в консоль
Подскажите пожалуйста, где и что не так делаю

Comment: Раз вы использовали стрелочную функцию, то она захватывает this из своего текущего окружения и не имеет никакого отношения к тому this, который задаётся где-то внутри jQuery

Comment: @andreymal спасибо большое, понял свою ошибку

Comment: `...click( evt => { console.log($(evt.target).attr('data-page')) })`